# Lay ImageView on top of ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have looked at the other links on here, and none of them have worked. I have a LinearLayout (the main container is a RelativeLayout), and then an ImageView and ImageView inside the LinearLayout. I am trying to lay a  play button on top of the main ImageView content.

Here is the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/attach_previews_facebook" android:paddingLeft="64.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="150dip" android:layout_marginRight="8.0dip" android:layout_below="@id/attach_articles"> 
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/attach_preview_1" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/videobtn" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/play_button"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout_weight does nothing except for laying the play button right next to the attach_preview_1 (instead of ontop of it).

Comment: use a FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `FrameLayout`. This `ViewGroup` stacks all `Views` on top of each other.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

**Note:** I highly suggest to use a `ImageButton` or borderless button instead of an `ImageView` for this type of task.

More info: [Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html), [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html), [Borderless](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless)

**Example code:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/attach_previews_facebook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/attach_articles"
    android:layout_marginRight="8.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="64.0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/attach_preview_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/videobtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/play_button"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a `Layer List` or `FrameLayout` :

## Layer List approch

**res/drawable/layers.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**This layout XML applies the drawable to a View:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/layers" />
```

**Result**

[image]

## FrameLayout approch

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/attach_previews_facebook" android:paddingLeft="64.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="150dip" android:layout_marginRight="8.0dip"
    >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/attach_preview_1" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/iconevaleurs"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/videobtn" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="127dp" android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/iconevaleurs"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]